# Converting a Map of subclass values to map of SuperClass values

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap, java-stream

I am converting a map containing sub class values to a map of super class values using the below listed approach. Is there a better / recommended way to achieve the same?

```
class SuperClass{
    private String name;
    // getters, setters and copyOf
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private String id;
    // getters and setters
}

Map<String, SuperClass> superClassMap = subclass
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, entry -> SuperClass.copyOf(entry.getValue()))
  );
```

EDIT:

Below is the reverse operation that I am performing -

```
superClassMap
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
          Entry::getKey,
          entry ->
            SubClass
              .builder()
              .setName(entry.getValue().getName())
              .setId(anotherMap.get(entry.getKey()).getId())
              .build()
        )
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Guava, you can get a mapped view like this:

```
Maps.transformValues(SuperClass:copyOf)
```

Otherwise, I'd say your way is fine. Or you might prefer this:

```
Map<String, SuperClass> superClassMap = new HashMap<>();
subclass.forEach((k, v) -> superClassMap.put(k, SuperClass.copyOf(v)));
```

Comment: Thanks @shmosel! I am indeed using Guava - this is awesome. Is there a way to do the reverse as well? (converting from map of super class to subclass)

Comment: You haven't described how one converts to the other, but it shouldn't be hard to adapt.

Comment: Thank you! I have added the code snippet. I am getting the values from another map. But since we have now made a `copy` , I assumed the original id values would have been preserved

Answer (score 1):

To modify all the values of the map, you can use Java 8 method [`Map.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.BiFunction)), which expects a `BiFunction` generating a *new value* based on the *previous value* and a *key*:

```
Map<String, SuperClass> superClass = new HashMap<>(subclass);

superClass.replaceAll((k, v) -> SuperClass.copyOf(v));
```

**Note:** [`HashMap`'s copy-constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Map)) expects an argument of type `Map<? extends K, ? extends V>`, therefore we can provide a Map having *values* of **subtype** without issues owing to upper-bounded wild card.

Comment: Only if `subclass` is a `Map<String, SuperClass>`.

Comment: @shmosel You're right, fixed.